# Некорректно работает бинарный поиск

Tags: c++, бинарный-поиск

Есть массив с 10 числами, необходимо ввести с клавиатуры еще k чисел, с помощью бинарного поиска найти эти числа в массиве и вывести на экран встречаются ли они в нём, если нет, то пропустить. Код почему-то находит только 1 и 3.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    int msv [] {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17};
    int k;

    cout << "Введите кол-во чисел: "; cin >> k;

    int *msvk {new int [k] {}};

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите элемент под номером " << i+1 << ": "; cin >> msvk[i];
    }

    int mid;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        int left = 0;
        int right = 8;

        while(true)
        {
            mid = (right - left)/2;

            if (msvk[i] == msv[mid])
            {
                cout << "Число " << msvk[i] << " повторяется" << '\n';
                break;            
            }
            if (msvk[i] < msv[mid])
                right = mid - 1;
            else
                left = mid + 1;
            
            if (left > right)
                break;
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Где средина, например, между 15 и 13?

Любой скажет: 14

Кроме вас. Потому что вы скажете — вот же она:

```
mid = (right - left)/2;
```

то есть (15-13)/2 == 1!

Дальше пояснять надо?